# How to get odds ratio from regression analysis when the response variable is continuous variable

Tags: odds-ratio

I want to use odds ratio for interpreting the association between indepednet variales and response variable, but my response variable is continuous variable. I don't know what analysis to do for obtaining odds ratio when the response variable is continuous variable. Can I calculate odds ratio from generalized linear mixed model using SPSS or R?

Comment: There are no odds (or probabilities) when your dependent variable is continuous.

Comment: Yes there are, if you are using the proportional odds model for continuous or ordinal Y.

Comment: Could you share an example data and add more context to your question?